# mysql trigger unable to get the value of foreign key using SELECT

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I have tables A and B. I'm writing trigger on table A as "After Insert" in which it has to refer some of the columns from table B, I need to get the values from both A and B tables then insert it into new table C. I get all the detail from table B using SELECT except the one column which is referred as foreignkey.

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` TRIGGER `test`.`files_AFTER_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `A` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT entryid,entrytype,fid,entryname 
    INTO @entryid, @entrytype,@fid,@entryname 
    FROM B 
    WHERE entryid=NEW.entryid;

    INSERT INTO C (entryid,entrytype,fid) 
    values (NEW.entryid, @entrytype,@fid);
END
```

`fid` - is foreignkey in table B.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: *except the one column which is referred as foreignkey* What column do you tell about? What are their names in both source and destination tables?

Answer (score 0):

UDV usage is excess:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` TRIGGER `test`.`files_AFTER_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `A` 
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO C (entryid, entrytype, fid) 
  SELECT entryid, entrytype, fid
  FROM B 
  WHERE entryid=NEW.entryid;
```